# backward arabic text in device

Tags: android, flash, sqlite, apache-flex, flash-builder

am developing mobile app and when i run the app the list show Arabic text backward

it works fine in the desktop debugger, but when i run the app on actual device it read backward.

desktop debugger works fine as you can see

[image: http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8/9wf2.jpg]

in this picture from the actual device galaxy s3 the text is backward although it worked fine on the desktop debugger.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first you should follow this steps :

1- download ArabicUtilities java class from here :https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

2- download the tahoma.ttf file for asset folder :http://www.4shared.com/file/AY2EIORg/tahoma.htm

3- for test all theme :

```
AssetManager manager=this.getAssets();
try
{
manager.open("tahoma.ttf");
TextView tv=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.testMe);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(manager, "tahoma.ttf"));
tv.setTextSize(50f);
tv.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape("الحمد لله"));
}catch(Exception ex){
//TODO
}
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: I assume this for android on eclipse ,how to implement this for flex android application?